A ceiling spotlight stays dimly lit
Inspired by this question, but not identical, I feel. In my case, I have several ceiling spotlights without any dimmer or similar - just bog-standard LED lights. I have noticed that every night, when I turn off the light, two of them stay very dimly lit all night - during the daytime, the light is too weak to see.
Is there any plausible way in which you might wire an LED light, intentionally or accidentally, so this happens - eg. to provide a sort of night-light like the ones you might put in a child's bedroom?

Is the switch absolutely just a physical on/off switch? Any "smarts", timer, light on the switch itself, etc.? "two of them" implies others don't light up - if you swap the bulbs around does the problem stay with the location or with the bulbs?

I don't have any 'smart' switches at all, so yes, this is just a physical on/off. The switch controls a number os these spotlights, and they are not the sort with a bulb; they all turn off as expected except those two.

You can put a capacitor in series with it (or in parallel with the switch) to limit the current available. Introduce that parasitic capacitance explicitly.
In fact that's what the cheapest LED models do a capacitor in series and then rectified and smoothed. Adding another capacitor in series will further limit the current.
Though the better option is to just install a low output decorative light than mess with the wiring.

Cannot this be done with LED rated dimmers and dimmable LED bulbs?  Why complicate things?
